# Implicite finite differences in two dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Consider the following PDE
\begin{align}
V(x,y) = F(x,y) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} f(x) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} g(y)
\end{align}

where $x$ and $y$ are states,  $V$ is the value function, $F$ the payoff function and $f$ and $g$ are the law of motions.

By $v^n$ we denote some approximation of $V$, where $n = 0,1,\ldots$ is the index of iterations. U use value function iteration and update via an implicit scheme
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1} - v^n}{\Delta} + v^{n+1} = F + \frac{\partial v^{n+1}}{\partial x} f + \frac{\partial v^{n+1}}{\partial y} g
\end{align}
where $\Delta$ is some scaling parameter (CFL condition).
I try to approximate $V$ over some finite and equidistant grid $(x_i,y_j)\in \{x_1,\ldots,x_I\}\times\{y_j, \ldots,y_J\}$. I have no boundary conditions, thus I use at $i = 1$ and $j = 1$ the respective forward difference and at $i=I$ and $j = J$ the backward difference. In between I use the central difference. That specification gives me 7 different equations for calculating $v^{n+1}$ dependending on $i$ and $j$. In particular

At $i=j=1$
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1}_{1,1} - v^n_{1,1}}{\Delta} + v^{n+1}_{1,1} = F_{1,1} + \frac{v^{n+1}_{2,1} - v^{n+1}_{1,1}}{\Delta x}  f_1 + \frac{v^{n+1}_{1,2} - v^{n+1}_{1,1}}{\Delta y} g_1
\end{align}

At $i=1$, $J > j > 1$
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1}_{1,j} - v^n_{1,j}}{\Delta} + v^{n+1}_{1,j} = F_{1,j} + \frac{v^{n+1}_{2,j} - v^{n+1}_{1,j}}{\Delta x}  f_1 + \frac{v^{n+1}_{1,j+1} - v^{n+1}_{1,j-1}}{2\Delta y} g_j
\end{align}

At $I > i > 1$, $j = 1$
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1}_{i,1} - v^n_{i,1}}{\Delta} + v^{n+1}_{i,1} = F_{i,1} + \frac{v^{n+1}_{i+1,1} - v^{n+1}_{i-1,1}}{2\Delta x}  f_i + \frac{v^{n+1}_{i,2} - v^{n+1}_{i,1}}{\Delta y} g_1
\end{align}

At $I > i>1$, $J > j > 1$
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1}_{i,j} - v^n_{i,j}}{\Delta} + v^{n+1}_{i,j} = F_{i,j} + \frac{v^{n+1}_{i+1,j} - v^{n+1}_{i-1,j}}{2\Delta x}  f_i + \frac{v^{n+1}_{i,j+1} - v^{n+1}_{i,j-1}}{2\Delta y} g_j
\end{align}

At $i=I$, $J > j > 1$
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1}_{I,j} - v^n_{I,j}}{\Delta} + v^{n+1}_{I,j} = F_{I,j} + \frac{v^{n+1}_{I,j} - v^{n+1}_{I-1,j}}{\Delta x}  f_I + \frac{v^{n+1}_{I,j+1} - v^{n+1}_{I,j-1}}{2\Delta y} g_j
\end{align}

At $I > i > 1$, $j = J$
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1}_{i,J} - v^n_{i,J}}{\Delta} + v^{n+1}_{i,J} = F_{i,J} + \frac{v^{n+1}_{i+1,J} - v^{n+1}_{i-1,J}}{2\Delta x}  f_i + \frac{v^{n+1}_{i,J} - v^{n+1}_{i,J-1}}{\Delta y} g_J
\end{align}

At $i = I$, $j = J$
\begin{align}
\frac{v^{n+1}_{I,J} - v^n_{I,J}}{\Delta} + v^{n+1}_{I,J} = F_{I,J} + \frac{v^{n+1}_{I,J} - v^{n+1}_{I-1,J}}{\Delta x}  f_I + \frac{v^{n+1}_{I,J} - v^{n+1}_{I,J-1}}{\Delta y} g_J
\end{align}
where $\Delta x := x_i - x_{i-1}$ and $\Delta y := y_j - y_{j-1}$.

I know that for the one dimensional case we would have three euqations ($i=1$, $1 < i <I$, $i = I$) and could write this more compact in matrix notation and solve $v^{n+1}$ by matrix inversion. However, I don't know how to write down this system compactly.

- Can you point me to literature where those kind of problems are discussed?
- Do have an idea how to compute $v^{n+1}$ efficiently?

I was thinking about to extend the one dimensional method. Firstly we may collect terms with $v^{n+1}_{(\cdot)}$ and have something like

\begin{align}
a v^{n+1}_{i-1,j-1} + b v^{n+1}_{i,j-1} + c v^{n+1}_{i-1,j} + d v^{n+1}_{i,j} + e v^{n+1}_{i+1,j} + h v^{n+1}_{i,j+1} + l v^{n+1}_{i+1,j+1} = F_{i,j} + \frac{v^n_{i,j}}{\Delta}
\end{align}
where greek symbols denote coeffcients.

Where for instance $a$ is given by
\begin{align}
a = 
\begin{cases}
0, &i=j=1\\
0, &i=1,J>j>1\\
0, &I>i>1,j=1\\
\frac{f_i}{2\Delta x} + \frac{g_j}{2\Delta y},\quad & I>i>1,J>j>1\\
\frac{f_i}{\Delta x} + \frac{g_j}{2\Delta y},\quad & i=I,J>j>1\\
\frac{f_i}{2\Delta x} + \frac{g_j}{\Delta y},\quad & I>i>1,j=J\\
\frac{f_i}{\Delta x} + \frac{g_j}{\Delta y},\quad & i=I,j=J\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Now I'd like to get a linear system of the form $Av^{n+1}=B$ where $A$ is a $IJ \times IJ$ matrix of coefficients $\{a,b,c,d,e,h,l\}$ and $v^{n+1}$ and $B$ are $IJ \times 1$ vectors, such that we can solve for $v^{n+1}=A^{-1}B$.

### Example: $I = J = 3$

I worked through a minimal example. Note that $v'_{(\cdot)}:=v^{n+1}_{(\cdot)}$. 
\begin{align}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
d & h & 0 & e & l & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
b & d & h & 0 & e & l & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & b & d & 0 & 0 & e & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
c & 0 & 0 & d & h & 0 & e & l & 0\\ 
a & c & 0 & b & d & h & 0 & e & l\\ 
0 & a & c & 0 & b & d & 0 & 0 & e\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & c & 0 & 0 & d & h & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & a & c & 0 & b & d & h\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & c & 0 & b & d 
\end{bmatrix}}_{=:A}
\times
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
v'_{11}\\ 
v'_{12}\\ 
v'_{13}\\ 
v'_{21}\\ 
v'_{22}\\ 
v'_{23}\\ 
v'_{31}\\ 
v'_{32}\\ 
v'_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}}_{=:v'} 
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{11}\\ 
B_{12}\\ 
B_{13}\\ 
B_{21}\\ 
B_{22}\\ 
B_{23}\\ 
B_{31}\\ 
B_{32}\\ 
B_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}}_{=:B}
\end{align}

There is some pattern in filling $A$ (look at the nine $3 \times 3$ matrices). Any idea how to automatize the filling by a double loop over $i$ and $j$?

Comment: It seems like you have everything worked out for two indices, so to automate it you just need to flatten the two dimensions into a single index (e.g. $(I,j) \mapsto J(i-1)+j$).  However since the matrix is very sparse you might want to use some Iterative method (conjugate gradient) to do the inversion.  In that case you wouldn't need to do any index mapping but just need to implement a "multiply by $A$" (and possibly $A^*$) function which can naturally take two dimensional inputs.

Comment: Thanks. Seen the single indexing here http://geodynamics.usc.edu/~becker/teaching/557/problem_sets/problem_set_fd_2dheat.pdf. Shame the matlab solution is not provided. Never heard of conjugate gradient methods. Gotta check it out. Would you mind providing a simlpe example which sketches the idea or how to get $A$ for that matter?

Comment: Take a look at this link, see the last page to know how to get such $A$ http://web.stanford.edu/~amsallem/PDEs_Lecture5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS A COMNENT, but much too long to be put into the comments section.

The calculus (such as done by clueless) might be simplified thanks to preliminary change of variables :

$$V(x,y) = F(x,y) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} f(x) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} g(y)$$

Let : $\begin{cases} X=\int \frac{dx}{f(x)} \\ Y=\int \frac{dy}{g(x)} \end{cases}\quad $ which allows the computation of the functions $x=x(X)$ and $y=y(Y)$

So, $V(x,y)=V\left(x(X),y(Y)\right)= V(X,Y)$ and $F(x,y)=F\left(x(X),y(Y)\right)= F(X,Y)$

The PDE is transformed into :
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial Y}-V(X,Y)=-F(X,Y)$$
This is a first order linear non-homogeneous PDE.

The associated homogeneous PDE : 
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial Y}-V(X,Y)=0$$
can be solved thanks to the method of characteristics. The set of characteristic equations is :
$$\frac{dX}{1}=\frac{dY}{1}=\frac{dV}{V}$$
from which two equations of characteristic curves can be derived :

First : $\quad X-Y=c_1$

Second : $\quad \frac{V}{X}=c_2$

The general solution of the homogeneous ODE on implicit form is :
$$f\left( X-Y \:,\:\frac{V}{X} \right)=0$$ 
where $f$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Or, expressed on explicit form :
$$V=X \: \Phi(X-Y)$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of one variable.

In order to find the general solution of the inhomogeneous PDE, one have to compute a particular solution $V_p$ of 
$$\frac{\partial V_p}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial V_p}{\partial Y}-V_p(X,Y)=-F(X,Y)$$
The general solution of the inhomogeneous PDE is :
$$V(X,Y)=V_p+X \: \Phi(X-Y)$$

The finite differences method of computation can be used to compute an approximate of $V_p$

As pointed out at the begining, this is not an answer to the question raised by clueless, but a comment suggesting a preliminary change of variables in order to simplify the form of the PDE. I don't know if this can be useful in the context of discretized calculus.